# Is Craft a good fit for a project w/ social network features?

Tags: users

I'm wondering if Craft would be a good fit for a project that would require social features like:

- users being able to submit content to the site
- users being able to 'like' content
- users being able to create 'folders/collections' and add/save content in them
- users being able to follow each other to keep up with each others content

Comment: You might also have a look at the [craft plugin library](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins). There are a number of plugins related to social functionality that you might be able to use as is, or extend.

Comment: I'm on the verge of releasing a plugin which allows users to "Like" content. Contact support@doublesecretagency.com if you'd like to beta test it.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Since my last comment, I've released [Upvote](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote), a plugin which lets you easily upvote/downvote, or simply "like" any element. Works for entries, assets, users, categories, tags, or even custom elements introduced by other plugins!

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on whether you consider Craft a platform, that you're willing to do some custom development on, or an off-the-shelf, finished product.

Even though I love Craft, I have to be honest. As an off-the-shelf product, and if the main goal of the project is building a social network, I think you're be better off choosing some other, more specialised, platform.

You can probably solve all the things you mention with Craft; user handling, posting content to different channels from the front-end, updating content with likes, updating users with followers, etc. But, you don't get any specific social network functionality "for free", you'll have to use the building blocks that exists in Craft to create this functionality.

But, if you're willing to do some custom plugin development, you could definitely use Craft as the platform. The plugin API is extremely powerful, and let's you build and integrate pretty much whatever you want into Craft.

Comment: I completely agree with this. I'm working on a very large project with some very complex interactions, and in that case I'm treating Craft as a platform. I'm very happy with how it's turning out, however it's requiring _a lot_ of custom plugin development. Per André's advice, **only take this on if you are very comfortable with plugin development** (or willing to learn it in depth).

Answer (score 3):

I was about to post a very similar question.

You have the following plugins available.

- **Guest Entries:** https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries
- **Like:** Lets you 'like' Entries, Assets etc - https://dukt.net/craft/like
- **Follow:** Lets you follow users and their entries etc - https://dukt.net/craft/follow
- Not sure about the folder/collections side of things.

There is a plugin coming for social account login but it's not released yet, I emailed the devloper but haven't had a reply - https://dukt.net/craft/social

I am going to go with ExpressionEngine if my deeper research find that Craft comes up short.

Personally I would prefer to use Craft but I'm new to it and am not sure I can to make it do what I need.

Let me know if you ended up going with Craft or went in a different direction.